# measure theory and decimal expansion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working on a problem on measure of decimal expansion and I want to confirm following. here $x \in [0,1]$.
$$\mu( \{ x: \text{digit }4\text{ appears but not digit 5 in the decimal expansion of } x\}) =: \mu(A)$$
Here $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.
My guess is $\mu(A) = 0$ since
$$ A\subset B := \{ x : \text{digit }5\text{ cannot appear in the decimal expansion of }x \}$$
Since $\mu(B) = 0$ and the completeness of the Lebesgue measure immediately imply $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B) = 0$.

Any comments and helps are greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I edited your post to become a bit less confusing. In general, your Idea is correct, but it remains to be prooved, that $A \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$ (The Borel $\sigma$-Algebra) and $\mu(B) = 0$ (**Hint**: use $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subset [0,1]$ dense). The real difficulty seems to be the proof of $A,B \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds fine to me.  All that is left is to prove your claim that $B$ is measurable and that $m(B)=0$.  Here is a fairly straightforward way to do this.

Form a sequence of nested subsets, $B_n$ whose infinite intersection is $B$.  Let $B_1$ be the $[0,1]\setminus[.5,.6)$ so that $m(B_1)=.9$.  Next, let

$$B_2=B_1\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=0}^9\left[\frac{m+.5}{10},\frac{m+.6}{10}\right)\right)$$

and notice that $m(B_2)=.9-9\cdot.01=.81$.  In general, we will have

$$B_{n+1}=B_{n}\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=0}^{10^{n}-1}\left[\frac{10^nm+5}{10^{n+1}},\frac{10^nm+6}{10^{n+1}}\right)\right)$$

and $m(B_{n+1})=m(B_n)-9^n\cdot10^{-n-1}=m(B_n)-(.9)^n\cdot10^{-1}$.  From this we can inductively show that $m(B_n)=.9^n$.  All the $B_n$ are measurable, so their intersection is as well, and the measure of the intersection is the limit of $m(B_n)=.9^n$, which is $0$.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Jared. I did prove m(B) = 0. It is almost identical to what Jared suggested..